# How do I dynamically reference variables in jMeter HTTP Requests?

Tags: jmeter

I'm setting up a test that needs to first read some json data and then build other http requests.

So I have some json that I retrieve first that is something like this:

```
Store Array
  -- Teams Array (Each store has some teams)
    -- Members (Each team has some members)
```

I created some BSF code to parse this out:

```
vars.put("team_id_" + teamIndx,teamArray.get(teamIndx).get("id").asString());
vars.put("associate_ids_" + teamIndx, memberIdList);
```

This works and I see the data in the debug sampler:

```
team_id_0=ABC
team_id_1=XYZ
associate_ids_0=92988,
associate_ids_1=105093,82959,95913,92256,31032,77896,
```

Now, I need to setup a loop controller (loop count = ${countOfTeams}) where I will need to pass in team_id_*indx* and associate_id_*indx* in the url:

```
&teamId=${team_id_<index>}&associateIds=${associate_ids_<index>}
```

However, I have tried several things (doing a counter, an __Eval etc..) but I cannot use a dynamic variable name to reference something that was setup by BSF.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like below;-

```
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
vars.get(“paramname_” + i)
}
```

Also, it is recommended to use groovy over beanshell for performance.

Kindly check if this helps.